# Numbering Data returned in table with various break points for restart

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table, #TEST, that lists a referenced Person Value (2), a Year for that person (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and a Dvalue for each year (100,100,150,100,100).

```
Year (int), DValue (Numeric(18,2)), Person (int)
```

I am attempting to get this to a final output of the person value, start year, end year, and value.

```
Person = 2, startyear = 1, endyear = 2, value = 100
Person = 2, startyear = 3, endyear = 3, value = 150
Person = 2, startyear = 4, endyear = 5, value = 100



SELECT 1 YEAR, 100 DVALUE, 2 PERSON
INTO #TEST
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 YEAR, 100 DVALUE, 2 PERSON
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 YEAR, 150 DVALUE, 2 PERSON
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 YEAR, 100 DVALUE, 2 PERSON
UNION ALL
SELECT 5 YEAR, 100 DVALUE, 2 PERSON
```

The above code will populate the data in the table.  I have attempted a few ordering options already which are included below with current output.

```
SELECT * 
  ,DDENSERANK = DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON , DVALUE  ORDER BY YEAR)
  ,DLAG = CASE WHEN LAG(DVALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON ORDER BY YEAR) IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE CASE WHEN A.DAMT = LAG(DVALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON ORDER BY YEAR) THEN 2 ELSE 1 END END
  ,DROWNUM = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON ORDER BY YEAR)
INTO #TESTFINAL
FROM #TEST  A
ORDER BY YEAR

SELECT DISTINCT *
  ,DDENSERANKA = DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON ,DLAG ,DVALUE ORDER BY YEAR)
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON , DLAG ORDER BY A.SYEAR)

FROM #TESTFINAL A
```

[image: OUTPUT_FROM_ABOVE]

My Dense_Rank continues numbering after a break in Year 3.  With Lag I run into issues with determining if the end year.  How can I number these differently or select from these so that I could see the start year and stop year of each DVALUE change by PERSON with an output like the following?

```
PERSON, DVALUE, STARTYEAR, ENDYEAR
2,      100,    1,         2
2,      150,    3,         3
2,      100,    4,         5
```

Current Output shows:

```
SELECT 
PERSON 
, DVALUE
, MIN(YEAR)
, MAX(YEAR)
FROM #TESTFINAL
GROUP BY PERSON, DVALUE

PERSON, DVALUE, STARTYEAR, ENDYEAR
2,      100,    1,         5
2,      150,    3,         3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```sql
drop table #test
SELECT 1 YEAR, 100 DVALUE, 2 PERSON
INTO #TEST
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 YEAR, 100 DVALUE, 2 PERSON
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 YEAR, 150 DVALUE, 2 PERSON
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 YEAR, 100 DVALUE, 2 PERSON
UNION ALL
SELECT 5 YEAR, 100 DVALUE, 2 PERSON

select person, dvalue, MIN(year) AS startyear, max(year) AS endyear
from (
    select count(case when prevvalue <> dvalue then 1 end) over(partition by person order by year) as cnt
    , *
    from (
        select *
        , LAG(DValue) OVER(PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY Year) AS prevValue
        from #TEST
        ) x
    ) x
group by person, dvalue, cnt
order by person, MIN(year)
```

It's a very standard LAG / COUNT technique which finds "groups" of same values as previous ones. After you have that, it's easy to GROUP BY and get the edges